# VBA: Public variable vs property

Tags: excel, vba, properties, public

I have 3 different modules and all of them have `Subs` that use at some stage the workbook the code is stored in. `Module3` is where my ranges are being set and I have also put the public workbook variable there. For clarification: the two main subs complete different tasks and have nothing to do with each other - except that both use some of the same range and row variables, that's why I put them in an extra module.

I also have a userform that uses `ThisWorkbook` in its `Initialize` event. So far I've been using a public variable to declare the workbook (`wbTest`) in `Module3`, but I've been reading up on properties, which I have never used before. I was thinking about passing the `wbTest` from `Module2` to the `Userform`, which I found out isn't possible for `Initialize` and that's how I came upon properties.

My question is: From examples I can see that it's fairly convenient to use properties when there is some kind of error handling or calculation associated with it. But in my case it is simply a `Set wbTest` command, nothing more - does choosing a property over a public variable still make sense in this case?

**Module1:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub MainSub1()
    Call Module3.DefiningRanges
    MsgBox wbTest.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

**Module2:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub MainSub2()
   Call Module3.DefiningRanges
   MsgBox wbTest.Range("A2").Value
   frmSelection.Show
End Sub
```

**Module3:**

```
Option Explicit
Public wbTest As Workbook

Public Sub DefiningRanges()
   Set wbTest = ThisWorkbook   
End Sub
```

**Userform frmSelection:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  MsgBox wbTest.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value
End Sub
```

So this is a fairly general question, but on google I haven't found a simple case like my one. I now do know that public variables are frowned upon and many try to avoid them if possible - that's why I'm asking if I should replace it with a property here.

Comment: What if instead using either, you just pass the wb variable as parameter for each function from the first?

Comment: I generally always use Properties even in the case of only setting the backing variable.  Why?  Mainly for consistency, although some purists will insist upon always using Properties.

Comment: @Damian Yeah, that seems like the easiest option. I overlooked this possibiliy because until today, when I was cleaning up my code, it would have been not as straightforward as it is now.Thank you!

Comment: @BrianMStafford If I were to use a property, I'd only have to use `Public Property Get`, right? I don't need to change the workbook once it's set, so `Property Set` isn't necessary?

Comment: @Alex Yes, you can do just the Property Get (read-only) or just the Property Set (write-only).  So with your current design just the Property Get should be good.

Answer (score 0):

as you're talking about using properties it sounds as though you want to use Module3 as an Object, in which case it needs to have been created as class module. That seems a bit overkill for simply returning a range - why don't you just convert it to a function that returns a range object? You could just change the Sub in Module3 as follows:

```
Public Function DefiningRanges() as WorkBook
   Set DefiningRanges = ThisWorkbook   
End Function
```

Then in your other modules you could create a new object and populate it with the result from this function as follows:

```
Private Sub MainSub1()
    Dim wb as WorkBook 
    Set wb = Module3.DefiningRanges()
    MsgBox wb.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Note that you no longer would refer to wbTest and I have replaced it with the new WorkBook [wb] in the MsgBox line. This way, there's no global variables, only a "global function" which returns a reference to the WorkBook.